# How can I install IDL 8.4 from .pkg installation file on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wine, pkg-config

I would like to install the IDL 8.4 on my Ubuntu 14.04... The installation requires starting the Install_IDLENVI.pkg installation app.

Everything I have tried so far following various advices on forums (wine, other windows apps,...) has not enabled me to start the installation program.

So, I wanted to kindly ask you to help me start the pkg file and therefore start the installation of IDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an Apple package.  If you're dual booting OSX and Ubuntu, install it under OSX.

If not, you've downloaded the wrong package.  Download the one for LINUX, not Mac OSX.

Comment: Thanks.  It curiously came as a part of UNIX distribution.